# Can we define the Gaussian distribution by taking the power of 2 instead of the exponential function?

Tags: normal-distribution

The probability density function of the Gaussian distribution is $1 / {\sqrt{2  \pi  \sigma^2} * e^{- {(x - \mu)^2}\over{2 \sigma^2}}}$. Can we instead define it as something like $1 / {\sqrt{2  \pi  \sigma^2} * 2^{- {(x - \mu)^2}\over{2 \sigma^2}}}$ and adjust the normalization so that it integrates to 1?

Comment: $2^x=e^{x\ln 2}$.

Comment: Your base-$e$ exponent needs a $-$ sign for the integral to be finite. I assume you also want such a sign in your base-$2$ exponent. Note that $2^{-z^2}=e^{-z^2\ln 2}$, so all you're doing is multiplying $\sigma$ by $1/\sqrt{\ln 2}$.